# Magezon blog sharing image

Tags: magento2

Does anybody know how to change the image of the link when sharing a blog using magezon?
for the image of the blog user

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check your page head section for the URL find where the "og:image" tag is and update your image thumbnail path over there.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="//cdn.example.com/uploads/images/webpage_300x200.png">
```